# how to give a variable path in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script where path can be 
`~/as-NY/com` or `~/as-LN/com` whatever is available. I can achieve this in K-shell as

`cd ~/as-(NY|LN)/com`, but not sure about bash. Can someone help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BASH you need to enable [`extglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) and do it like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd ~/as-@(NY|LN)/com
```